# Turning off custom errors for a web performance test

Tags: vb.net

I have a web test that I'm trying to turn off CustomErrors for, with code that looks like this:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.Rules
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports Test.AppFx.LoadTesting.Platform


Namespace Test.AppFx.LoadTesting.Enterprise

    Public Class Prospect_Init
        Inherits ThreadedWebTest

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
            Me.PreAuthenticate = True
        End Sub






        Public Overrides Sub Run()
            'Initialize validation rules that apply to all requests in the WebTest
            If (Me.Context.ValidationLevel >= Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.ValidationLevel.Low) Then
                Dim validationRule1 As ValidateResponseUrl = New ValidateResponseUrl()
                AddHandler ValidateResponse, AddressOf validationRule1.Validate
            End If
            If (Me.Context.ValidationLevel >= Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.ValidationLevel.Low) Then
                Dim validationRule2 As ValidationRuleResponseTimeGoal = New ValidationRuleResponseTimeGoal()
                validationRule2.Tolerance = 0.0R
                AddHandler ValidateResponseOnPageComplete, AddressOf validationRule2.Validate
            End If

            ' What ever roles are required for the tests in this scenario should be defined here. All 
            ' tests in the scenario will share them. 

            Dim roles() As String = {"Prospects Area"}

            'Login
            Prospects_Helper.Prospects_Login(Me, roles)

        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

All of this runs prior to a given test, and this particular piece of code currently runs into an error during a load test. To help me troubleshoot this problem, I need to disable custom errors. I've found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.customerrorssection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I know I need to define the mode as Off, but I have no idea what exactly I would need to declare (as I work more in T-SQL than VB at this point and am not as familiar with the architecture).

Could someone help me understand what I need to add to turn the custom errors off here?

Comment: Simple setting `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in web.config doesn't do the trick?

Comment: I can't figure out which web.config to put that in, because I'm not compiling the code to an executable. It's part of a load test that runs remotely (initiated on my machine, flowing through a load test controller [where the errors occur] and then to agents), so there's a lot of moving parts there.

Comment: Wait, is this a Web application, Winform executable or something else?

Comment: Load test for a web application. That code helps run the test.